# Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox

I have downloaded and installed the newest [virtualbox 4.3.20](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for my `Windows 7 (64-bit OS)`, but when I want to install `64-bit Linux`, the *New*->*Create Virtual Machine* only displays `32-bit` option, no `64-bit` option. Could anyone give any clues about this issue? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You're sure  you installed the `amd64` version, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a 64-bit VirtualBox archive on a 32-bit machine](http://superuser.com/questions/389251/running-a-64-bit-virtualbox-archive-on-a-32-bit-machine)

Comment: @Ramhound: Not a duplicate, this is for a 64-bit host.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson My comment was submitted 3.5 years ago.

Comment: To remedy this on my Win10 machine I needed to go into Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features and Turn Windows Features on or off. From here I needed to UNCHECK the Hyper-V feature that was installed. After rebooting the machine, the 64bit options were displayed

Comment: In addition to disabling the Hyper-V feature in the Windows features, I additionally had to go to the Task Manager and manually stop all running "Hyper-V ..." services and the "HV Host Service" from the "Services" tab. After rebooting, the 64bit options were finally displayed.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Take a look: http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/

If VirtualBox is only showing 32-bit versions in the Version list make sure:

- You have an x64 CPU installed. (Optimally, [a 64-bit OS should also be installed to receive acceptable virtualization performance](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests).)
- Hardware virtualization is enabled in the BIOS. (Your CPU must support it.)

  - For Intel x64: VT-x (Intel Virtualization Technology) and VT-d are both enabled
  - For AMD x64: AMD SVM (Secure Virtual Machine) is enabled
- Hyper-V (or any other form of bare-metal hypervisor) is not installed

Comment: @Tonny On top of this, as far as I remember, if you try to start something like XP Mode when you have VirtualBox VMs running, it will shut down your VirtualBox VMs abruptly without warning.

Comment: @Bruno I never used XP Mode myself. But I do know it is basically a version of Hyper-V that is dumbed down to just provide a XP VM and nothing else. I'll take your word for it that it shows such behavior. Makes sort of sense to prevent conflicts with other hypervisors and the people who would typically run XPMode would most likely not run another hypervisor anyway. Even so...Without warning is just being a jerk IMHO.

Comment: @duDE How I can use Hyper-V and Virtualbox at the same time?

Comment: @ user2284570: Nope, you can't: only one hypervisor can run at a time

Comment: On win7, after installing VB a restart was required to get the 64 bit options.

Comment: Any technical reason as to why Hyper-V be disabled? I mean, Virtual box gives the option of 32 bit virtualization even when Hyper-v is enabled; so why not 64 bit?

Comment: What do I do if following these instructions does not fix the problem?

Comment: Did the steps mentioned in this answer and the 64 bit versions still don't show up!

Comment: What do you do if your motherboard doesn't support this?

Comment: I know this question is about Win7 but since it was the first that popped up for my Win10 search without solving it, I thought I'd add a link to the fix here, I know it's from VMware and about BSOD but the fix is the same: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson Thank you, Andreas for sharing this helpful link!

Comment: VT-d is not needed. I tested this on a laptop with an Intel® Core™ i5-430M Processor which doesn't have this functionality.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to emulate 64 bit apps on a 64 bit host, your cpu needs a feature for that. Which duDE says, is an intel-specific copy-paste. The same support exists on AMDs too, there its name is AMD-v - maybe he forgot to mention.

If your cpu doesn't have this support, it won't ever work. If it has, maybe you need to switch this on in your bios.

There are bad BIOSes which can't turn this feature on. Sometimes a BIOS upgrade can in this case help.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem, only seeing 32-bit versions for the host OS's. Started working after updating asus p8z77-v pro bios to latest and enabling virtualization support. Before the bios update, virtubox showed only 32-bit OS's.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 creators update needed a restart to show the 64 bit OS options in VirtualBox 5.1.22 for my AMD Phenom (tm) II.

Also, the problem might be that you need to TURN OFF the computer after changing the Virtualization options in BIOS, not just restart it.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 1903 and Dell laptop, disabling Device Guard using group policy helped to enable 64 bit OS in VirtualBox.

For reference, https://appuals.com/fix-virtualbox-not-showing-64-bit-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

Using the guidance in the answer by @Leo Chapiro I was able to install Debian Buster 10 with Gnome on Windows 10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad. Here's the step-by step way I enabled the 64 bit option in VirtualBox:

- Restart PC and access BIOS with F1
- Play with arrow keys and enter to access 'Security > Virtualization' section
- Check the following options are enabled then F10 to save and exit:

[image]

When Windows boots, windows key, type 'Turn windows features on or off', open it and disable HyperV:

[image]

Open VirtualBox, it should now allow you to specify a 64bit version.

(I'm using the [Debian 10.7.0 amd64 with Gnome iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.7.0-amd64-gnome.iso) from the official images page -
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)

(I followed [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/install_debian10_virtualbox/) to install on VirtualBox)

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with Windows 10, so here is my solution.

Select the Control Panel. Use the Windows 10 Control Panel view, not the legacy view with large/small icons.

Select Programs.

Then under "Turn Windows Features on or off" tick the box Virtual Machine Platform and reboot

[image]