# Cannot run VirtualBox after crash, acceleration not available

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vt-x

I know that has a lot of topic like this, I've tried them a lot as well but my problem is not solved. My laptop has Core i3 and I used to use VBox just a few days before. When RAM got up to 99% my laptop crashed. I had to restart and now I cannot run VB again although VT-x is enabled and Hyper-V is disabled.

*Acceleration* tab is disabled:

[image: Acceleration tab greyed out]

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7/866963#866963 and http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. Reset BIOS to defaults.
2. Boot to Windows.
3. If VT-x is disabled in BIOS, enable it.

Some BIOS-es have bugs that cause features to become unavailable after crash, despite being enabled. Re-enabling them requires some voodoo. Resetting BIOS is usually effective, as it erases entire bios settings memory, including "crash memory".