# How do I stop Hyper-V from being re-installed/enabled automatically?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit, hyper-v

I use VirtualBox on Windows 10 and have a recurring problem where Hyper-V prevents me from using any guest OSes in 64-bit mode.  Basically, Hyper-V being installed (and running by default) only allows 32-bit mode in guest OSes.

I've un-installed Hyper-V from the Windows Feature List and restarted, which fixes the problem.  However, every few months I need to create a new VM base don a 64-bit guest OS and I can't, because Hyper-V is back and running.  I definitely didn't do it and was never presented with an option that would include this, so can only conclude that it was enabled by a Windows update or some other scheduled event.

How would I prevent this from happening?  Is there an related process that might be requiring Hyper-V and thus installing/enabling it by default?  I am not using anything VM-based other than VirtualBox.

For reference, I fixed my original problem (not having 64-bit guests as an option when creating a new VM) via this issue:

[Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)