# VirtualBox on Windows 10 64bit doesn't have a 64bit option

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I've read previous threads about this issue, but none seemed to help.

I'm running a 64bit version of Windows 10 on a HP Elitebook. I've installed VirtualBox and wanted to create a 64bit Linux VM. However, I can only select 32bit OS'es in VirtualBox.

In the BIOS, I've got both VT-x and VT-d enable, and I've disabled HyperV in Windows, but I still don't have the option to select a 64bit OS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you have security software that is interfering with VirtualBox's ability to use the VT-x and VT-d extensions.

Comment: Any way to check what's causing the problem?

Comment: You will need to determine which application (which is very likely your security software) thats causing the conflict and disable the conflicting application feature.

Answer (score 3):

## Turn off Core Isolation in Windows Defender

If [duDE's solution](https://superuser.com/a/866963/) didn't work, check Windows Defender > Device Security > Core Isolation Details and make sure this setting is turned **off**.

> Core isolation [includes] security features available on your device that use virtualization-based security

Which is why Core Isolation interferes with VirtualBox.

[image: Switch under "Core Isolation" > "Memory Integrity" is set to "Off"]