# Virtualization not enabled for i7 920 on EVGA x58 Classified SLI

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I have a good one for you guys. Here is my setup:

- EVGA x58 Classified Motherboard (LGA1366)
- Intel Core i7 920 @2.67 Ghz (45nm)

My issue is: I cannot get 64 bit virtual machines setup. Virtual Box shows only 32 bit options.

NOTE: This used to work, but no longer after reset & re-install of Windows 10.

This is what I've done to troubleshoot:

- BIOS Main Menu--> Frequency/Voltage control--> CPU Feature--> Virtualization Technology(Enabled this)
- Made sure Hyper-V is not installed.
- Triple-checked Core i7 920 specs to make sure Virtualization is supported: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37147/intel-core-i7-920-processor-8m-cache-2-66-ghz-4-80-gt-s-intel-qpi.html
- Downloaded the Intel Processor Identification Utility - which tells me that Virtualization Technology isn't supported... ??? (See Figure 1 below)
- Core isolation/memory integrity is turned off.
- I've fully shut down the computer and started it again rather than only using restarts after enabling Virtualization in the BIOS.
- I have the most recent version of Windows 10 (as of 5/20/2019)
- I have uninstalled Avast and all virus scanners/firewalls, and have a very bare-bones system with no obvious software which would restrict virtualization settings.

Figure 1: (click it for image)
[Core i7 920 identification utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0C1V.png)

So... what I've tried covers all suggestions I can find online including the link and links of the link that the moderator posted above :(, and I've been trying for a couple days.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: You either have Core Isolation turned on or you have AV software installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox on Windows 10 64bit doesn't have a 64bit option](https://superuser.com/questions/1211629/virtualbox-on-windows-10-64bit-doesnt-have-a-64bit-option)

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Please provide the exact build number you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.503)

Comment: What security software do you have installed[.](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)

Comment: @Ramhound - Avast Free Antivirus

Comment: You should include that vital information in your question.  Do you have `Enable Avast Self-defense module` enabled or disabled?  Within `C:\ProgramData\AVAST Software\avast\avast5.ini`, provide the entire line, that contains `VirtualizationMechanisms`.  Do you have Avast's hardware-assisted virtualization enabled or disabled

Comment: Since you have Avast installed, and Avast has the ability to use the virtualization technology, the fact you have Avast installed and configured to use VT-x is the reason VirtualBox is unable to use it.  Since you have not provided any information about what version of Avast you have installed.  I cannot research what the feature is called in the version you are using.  I only know the feature does exist and is the reason you cannot use VirtualBox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1241956/virtualbox-only-allowing-32-bit-os

Comment: Well, I turned off the Avast Hardware Virtualization Protection setting, and restarted, and that didn't work. So I uninstalled Avast+restart and that didn't work. I also checked for programs that might affect this, and I have none, its a pretty bare bones system. I'm wondering if it might be something with the "Execute Disable Bit" setting being turned on in the BIOS.