# 64-bit option missing for Ubuntu guest on Windows 10 host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, virtualization

Any thoughts? I've already tried whatever I found on web, still no luck.

**Problem**: While trying to create a new Ubuntu Guest VM on my Windows 10 Laptop using Virtual Box (v5.2.6 r120293), I see no option for a 64 bit guest OS.
[image: Problem]

---

**Symptoms:**

- It's a 64-bit Host OS:
  [image]
- My CPU [supports Intel VT-x](https://ark.intel.com/products/78937/Intel-Core-i7-4810MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz)
- Intel Virtualization is enabled in BIOS.
- Microsoft Hyper-V is disabled:
  [image]
- Windows defender (which controls Credential and Device Guard AFAIK) is disabled:
  [image]
- Anti-virus is Trend Micro Office Scan:
  [image]
- When I booted from an Ubuntu 64 bit ISO, it said *hardware only supports  i386, the OS you're booting to requires x86_64*. Or something like that

---

I read these:

- [Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=62339

Comment: So you read the duplicate.  What security software do you have installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Trend Micro. It's my office laptop. VT-x is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Security software is notorious for using VT-x.  “Trend Micro” isn’t specific enough I can do any research.

Comment: **The usual culprits are system level debuggers, other VM platforms, and some resident anti-virus applications.** - Update your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the "About" of anti-virus if that helps. I did have "VMWare Horizon Client", which I uninstalled before installing VirtualBox. Don't know if there are any system level debuggers, I didn't start any.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t indicate which Trend Micro product you have.  What version of VirtualBox?  You are going to have to determine if you have debuggers installed.  It’s your system, ask whom ever you have to ask, to determine the answer to that question.  Visual Studio has a debugger.  If you had docker installed in the past, that’s been an issue for some, update your question.

Comment: (If your screenshot indicates which Trend Micro product your using I don’t see it).  I prefer you just write what product you have installed as text

Comment: Did you try booting the device with a 64bit ISO in the virtual drive?

Comment: [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/5982/processors/processor-utilities-and-programs/intel-processor-identification-utility.html) download tool and submit the results.  Securable might be helpful also

Comment: @Ramhound It's Trend Micro Office Scan. Didn't have Docker, did have VS, which I'm trying to remove. Did try 64 bit ISO in generic VM, it threw compatibility error. Will post more tomorrow I think.

Comment: i386 indicates VBox was trying to boot a 64-bit OS within a 32-bit VM

Comment: [Office Scan appears to have the ability to scan VMs, if I were a betting man, it’s incompatible with VirtualBox](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1056376)

Comment: hmm. I'm onto removing the last VS component, lets see what happens after that. Anti-virus can't be removed as it's work laptop. :-(

Comment: @Ramhound So I removed the VS, but it's the same situation. So I guess it might be the anti-virus. Thanks for the effort/inputs!