# Trying to install Kali linux as virtual machine | Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I have a windows PC with a x-370 gaming k7 MOBO and im trying to build a Kali VM. Unfortunately i can only choose 32 bit OS's and I looked online and was told to check my bios settings but couldn't find anything other than some emulation 60-64 bit thing but that didn't work. Im trying to be able to choose a 64 bit OS in virtual box.

Comment: 1. Check if you have 64bit virsion of win
 2. Check BIOS for VTx/Virtualization options they should be enabled.

Comment: im pretty sure the problems not with bios rn. Also what is win 2?

Comment: Sorry miss-click the 2 shouldnt be there. And no without virtualization support build in processor and enabled in bios virtualBox can't emulate x64 only x86

Comment: i read somewhere that it should be enabled by default on my MOBO. I still dont know win is.

Comment: win = windows, `read somewhere` if your pc don't support it you are out of luck with x64 virtualization

Comment: i do have 64 bit version of windows and im sure it does support it because i have done it before. And as i said im pretty sure its nothing to do with my BIOS because the difference between now and before is that i reset windows after the first time.

Comment: No? And what about those [1](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7) [2](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/#.XLhAu6dfhhE) [3](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=86449) [4](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=89941)

Comment: 2 things.
1. You said no but i didn't ask a question
2. Im here to fix my problem not to argue. Ill check them out

Comment: What is your processor? Some low-end ones don't support the VT-X stuff.

Comment: I have a ryzen 5 1600x

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=82323

Comment: @xenoid im pretty sure that's not the problem because i managed to do it before.