# Running Windows 7 virtual machine without VT-x

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-player, vt-x

I have a Laptop with Intel Core i7-8665U processor running Windows 10.

I need a Windows 7 virtual machine. I tried VMWare Player. It says that I need to activate VT-x in the BIOS. Since this is a company laptop the BIOS is password protected and I don't think I'll get it.

How can I run a Windows 7 VM on my machine without VT-x? I don't care if it is Windows 7 x86 or x64. I tried both and get the same error message when I try to start the VM.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Virtualbox will run 32 bit guest without having VT-x enabled according to their [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt).  There are lots of questions here about Virtualbox being limited to 32 bit without VT-x (for example [Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/866963/269373)) so if a x86 guest is OK you could try that.